# Coupon not working in Magento 1.9.3.1 with HHVM and PHP 7

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, quote

I just upgraded my Magento from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.1. FYI, I'm using HHVM 3.15 not Zend. Everything works fine, except for the coupon. I noticed even when using vanilla installation, problem exists.

I tried to dig deeper with the `couponPostAction()` method (`Mage_Checkout_CartController`) and pay attention to this line:

```
$this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')->collectTotals()->save();
```

I also checked the **sales_flat_quote** table and found that `subtotal_with_discount` and `base_subtotal_with_discount` fields are already correct, however the the `grand_total` and `base_grand_total` are not because both are still showing the original amount.

I couldn't figure it out why the quote model didn't calculate the discount amount and save to `grand_total` and `base_grand_total` correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried with PHP 7 and the problem appears to be the same. It works on PHP 5.5

Comment: It appeared the collector order was out of whack. Fix with this module https://github.com/hartmut-co-uk/magento-php7-totals-fix

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your server to php 7 then this issue arise.

This module fixed things up for me: https://github.com/hartmut-co-uk/magento-php7-totals-fix